# Large table query cause Java OutOfMemory

Tags: java, sql-server, out-of-memory

I have a Spring Boot application which is using JDBCTemplate to query a large SQL Server table.
Sometimes it cause Java OutOfMemory error since the query's taking all records of the table to a List and then performing pagination on it.

Now I'm trying to resolve the issue by implementing pagination on Database-side (ie. using SQL Limit/Offset and RowNum), but doing that require a huge change on project sourcecode base.

Is there any other way to resolve this problem?

Comment: Pagination is fine, but do you really expect that user is going to click through two millions of pages? You need filtering to get the data user needs to work with. And it would solve your memory problems too.

Comment: Actually it just "some" hundreds pages (that too much anyway), with each page has about 10 records so there will be like thousands of object created in memory. I don't know if it will be enough to cause java heap memory overflow, or there are other flaws in the implemented pagination.

Comment: Paging w/ Infinite scroll, Batching, and Streaming are all pains to implement but once you do it your data sets can grow (nearly)indefinitely, while performance remains the same. If this project is supposed to be "future proof" then Paging w/ Infinite scroll, Batching, and Streaming are the next logical steps. If the project is in maintenance mode eat the errors or force the user to filter results.